# (Easier) Switch between vehicle inventory?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I currently have 4 vehicles at my base: My spaceship, a Colossus, a Roamer and a Nomad, all with their own inventories.

How can I switch between this inventories without entering the vehicle first and then exchange the items? I know I can store items directly to the single inventory, but to organize or exchange items, I'm looking for an easier way.

*If it makes a difference: I'm playing with the Synthesis update v2.23.*

Comment: The venicle inventory in the character screen was always using currently active (last summoned) vehicle. I don't remember reading about any change in last update to this or to ship inventories. So you have to activate another vehicle/ship if you want to access its inventory.

Answer (score 1):

To my experience you can access starship, frigate, exocraft and storage inventories as long as you are close enough to them - through the tabbed view or shortcut for moving items. But for example ships, you have access only to last one used (active).